# Kotlin unable to request JSON files with more than one directory in URL?

Tags: json, parsing, kotlin, url

While trying to download and parse JSON files through Kotlin, it kept failing trying to access the document, though trying different (shorter) URLS seemed to work fine

```
val string = "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/11.2.1/data/en_GB/champion.json"
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        val request = Request.Builder().url(string).build()

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback
        {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val body = response.body?.string()
                println(body)
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                println("Failed")
            }
        })
```

This gives the "Failed" output in the console:[failed#1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1Fvv.png)

However, using a shorter URL such as this:

```
val string = "https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/api/versions.json"
```

Gives the correct output: [working #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCD91.png)

Anyone know why and/or a fix to this?

Thanks!

---

Update:

Trying with a file that is considerably smaller than the first, but includes two directories instead of one:

```
val string = "http://static.developer.riotgames.com/docs/lol/maps.json"
```

Still ends up failing leading me to believe it is unable to access the document if it is too nested within directories?

Comment: Is there anything else in the output console besides that brief failed message?

Comment: Unfortunately not, as it comes from the Println when it catches the exception, otherwise the program will crash entirely when trying to access the json, unsure if it's an overflow and the file is too long?